# Issue with rendering control on Async postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm using this gauge in my contentplaceholder.

http://www.dariancabot.com/projects/jgauge_wip/

Script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Scripts/jgauge.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jgauge-0.3.0.a3.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jQueryRotate.2.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/excanvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var demoGauge1 = new jGauge(); // Create a new jGauge.
    demoGauge1.id = 'jGaugeDemo1'; // Link the new jGauge to the placeholder DIV.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        demoGauge1.init(); // Put the jGauge on the page by initializing it.
    });
</script>
```

Markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="jGaugeDemo1" class="jgauge"></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myBtn" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="myBtn" runat="server" Text="Refresh" />
```

I have script manager on master page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

But after async postback (hitting 'myBtn'), gauge disappears. Help.

Comment: On an async postback, the entire contents inside the updatepanel are recreated - your `demoGauge1` is no longer referencing the same `jGuageDemo1` div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since html elements insice the update panel are recreated on every async postback, you'll need to regenerate the gauge on every request.

I don't have experience with that gauge control but something like this could do the trick

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(onEndRequest);

function onEndRequest(sender, args){    
   demoGauge1.init();       
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But I was able to recreate gauge again on async postback, but it's internal values were not displayed. I saw with firebug, that values are there on the page. But not getting rendered. So I'm clueless about it.

Comment: I'm afraid that without knowing the control I can't say very much about it. You may try to take a look to the control code to see what's wrong. Maybe you need to create a different gauge instead of using the same you already had?